# Setting a dynamic pdf filename to my visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I would like to set a dynamic pdf filename to my visualforce page

Thé code is below, however this code still generated pdf with visualforce page generic name? 
(This code is Just to test to set a different static file name, bu it does not work)

I appreciate an comment or advice

```
<apex:page standardController="Invoice1__c" showHeader="true" renderAs="pdf" language="tr">
```

.

```
public Invoice1__c() 
{
    PageReference p =
Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=AccountReport.pdf');
}

// my main code is here //

...
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `contentType` attribute on the VF-Page itself:

```
<apex:page contentType="application/pdf#SomeName{!'including dynamic components'}.pdf">
```

The key here is, of course, the `#` after the content-type.

**Edit**

I should have read on in my code, sorry! What you need to do is: Create a page, say testPDF and put this code in:

```
<apex:page contentType="application/pdf#SomeName{!'including dynamic components'}.pdf">
<apex:include pageName="testPDF_content"/></apex:page>
```

Then, create a second page testPDF_content, and let the code be like this:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">Content...</apex:page>
```

Now you can call testPDF and it will be downloaded as a PDF with the filename you specified, you can try this here:

[dev-sep.force.com/test/testPDF](http://dev-sep.force.com/test/testPDF)

Comment: Hi , contenttype attribute does not work for pdf files

Comment: Indeed, I should have read on in my code, sorry!
What you need to do is: Create a page, say `testPDF` and put this code in: `<apex:page contentType="application/pdf#SomeName{!'including dynamic components'}.pdf"><apex:include pageName="testPDF_content"/></apex:page>`.

Then, create a second page `testPDF_content`, and let the code be like this: `<apex:page renderAs="pdf">Content...</apex:page>`.

Now you can call `testPDF` and it will be downloaded as a PDF with the filename you specified, you can try this here: http://dev-sep.force.com/test/testPDF